# How do I force the text off the screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, text, ide

[image: screenshot]

I don't want the text to come back left. I want it to go off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have line wraps enabled.

```
Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General
```

Uncheck 'Use soft wraps in editor'